# My first attemp to create a wordlist,

Tags: c, loops, word-list

I'm trying to create a wordlist that contains all the combination of letters(uppercase and lowercase) and some symbols. Basically most of the ASCII table.

I was just curios about how much memory the text file will occupy . I think i will use some other functions to delete unnecessary words. But for now i pray that my 1 TB hard disk won't blow up.
I don't know if this method is the right metod, using nested for loops with subscripted array, maybe i should use linked list for better performance. In the meantime i can create functions that delete lines with more characters than some tot.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PATH "wordlist.txt"
#define SIZE 68



void Write(char * word[], FILE * f, int N)
{
for(int i = 0; i <= N; i++)
  {
  fprintf(f,"%s", word[i]);
  }
  fprintf(f,"\n");
}




void thirteen_Digits(char * word[],char * letters[] , FILE * f)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
    word[0] = letters[i];
    for(int j = 0; j < SIZE ;j++)
      {
        word[1] = letters[j];
        for(int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++)
        {
          word[2] = letters[k];
          for(int l = 0; l < SIZE;l++)
          {
            word[3] = letters[l];
            for(int m = 0; m< SIZE; m++)
            {
              word[4] = letters[m];
              for(int n = 0; n < SIZE; n++)
              {
                word[5] = letters[n];
                for(int o = 0; o < SIZE; o++)
                {
                  word[6] = letters[o];
                  for(int p = 0; p < SIZE; p++)
                  {
                    word[7] = letters[p];
                    for(int q = 0; q < SIZE; q++)
                    {
                      word[8] = letters[q];
                      for(int r = 0; r < SIZE; r++)
                      {
                        word[9] = letters[r];
                        for(int s = 0; s < SIZE;s++)
                        {
                          word[10] = letters[s];
                          for(int t = 0; t < SIZE; t++)
                          {
                            word[11] = letters[t];
                            for(int u = 0; u < SIZE; u++)
                            {
                              word[12] = letters[u];
                              Write(word, f, 12);
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

fclose(f);
}

void twelve_Digits(char * word[],char * letters[] , FILE * f)
{
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
  word[0] = letters[i];
  for(int j = 0; j < SIZE ;j++)
    {
      word[1] = letters[j];
      for(int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++)
      {
        word[2] = letters[k];
        for(int l = 0; l < SIZE;l++)
        {
          word[3] = letters[l];
          for(int m = 0; m< SIZE; m++)
          {
            word[4] = letters[m];
            for(int n = 0; n < SIZE; n++)
            {
              word[5] = letters[n];
              for(int o = 0; o < SIZE; o++)
              {
                word[6] = letters[o];
                for(int p = 0; p < SIZE; p++)
                {
                  word[7] = letters[p];
                  for(int q = 0; q < SIZE; q++)
                  {
                    word[8] = letters[q];
                    for(int r = 0; r < SIZE; r++)
                    {
                      word[9] = letters[r];
                      for(int s = 0; s < SIZE;s++)
                      {
                        word[10] = letters[s];
                        for(int t = 0; t < SIZE; t++)
                        {
                          word[11] = letters[t];
                          Write(word, f,11);
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

void eleven_Digits(char * word[],char * letters[] , FILE * f)
{
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
  word[0] = letters[i];
  for(int j = 0; j < SIZE ;j++)
    {
      word[1] = letters[j];
      for(int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++)
      {
        word[2] = letters[k];
        for(int l = 0; l < SIZE;l++)
        {
          word[3] = letters[l];
          for(int m = 0; m< SIZE; m++)
          {
            word[4] = letters[m];
            for(int n = 0; n < SIZE; n++)
            {
              word[5] = letters[n];
              for(int o = 0; o < SIZE; o++)
              {
                word[6] = letters[o];
                for(int p = 0; p < SIZE; p++)
                {
                  word[7] = letters[p];
                  for(int q = 0; q < SIZE; q++)
                  {
                    word[8] = letters[q];
                    for(int r = 0; r < SIZE; r++)
                    {
                      word[9] = letters[r];
                      for(int s = 0; s < SIZE;s++)
                      {
                        word[10] = letters[s];
                        Write(word, f,10);
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

void ten_Digits(char * word[],char * letters[] , FILE * f)
{
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
  word[0] = letters[i];
  for(int j = 0; j < SIZE ;j++)
    {
      word[1] = letters[j];
      for(int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++)
      {
        word[2] = letters[k];
        for(int l = 0; l < SIZE;l++)
        {
          word[3] = letters[l];
          for(int m = 0; m< SIZE; m++)
          {
            word[4] = letters[m];
            for(int n = 0; n < SIZE; n++)
            {
              word[5] = letters[n];
              for(int o = 0; o < SIZE; o++)
              {
                word[6] = letters[o];
                for(int p = 0; p < SIZE; p++)
                {
                  word[7] = letters[p];
                  for(int q = 0; q < SIZE; q++)
                  {
                    word[8] = letters[q];
                    for(int r = 0; r < SIZE; r++)
                    {
                      word[9] = letters[r];
                      Write(word, f,9);
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

void nine_Digits(char * word[], char * letters[] ,FILE * f)
{
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
  word[0] = letters[i];
  for(int j = 0; j < SIZE ;j++)
    {
      word[1] = letters[j];
      for(int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++)
      {
        word[2] = letters[k];
        for(int l = 0; l < SIZE;l++)
        {
          word[3] = letters[l];
          for(int m = 0; m< SIZE; m++)
          {
            word[4] = letters[m];
            for(int n = 0; n < SIZE; n++)
            {
              word[5] = letters[n];
              for(int o = 0; o < SIZE; o++)
              {
                word[6] = letters[o];
                for(int p = 0; p < SIZE; p++)
                {
                  word[7] = letters[p];
                  for(int q = 0; q < SIZE; q++)
                  {
                    word[8] = letters[q];
                    Write(word, f,  8);
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

void eight_Digits(char * word[],char * letters[] , FILE * f)
{
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
  word[0] = letters[i];
  for(int j = 0; j < SIZE ;j++)
    {
      word[1] = letters[j];
      for(int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++)
      {
        word[2] = letters[k];
        for(int l = 0; l < SIZE;l++)
        {
          word[3] = letters[l];
          for(int m = 0; m< SIZE; m++)
          {
            word[4] = letters[m];
            for(int n = 0; n < SIZE; n++)
            {
              word[5] = letters[n];
              for(int o = 0; o < SIZE; o++)
              {
                word[6] = letters[o];
                for(int p = 0; p < SIZE; p++)
                {
                  word[7] = letters[p];
                  Write(word, f, 7);
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

void seven_Digits(char * word[], char * letters[] ,FILE * f)
{
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
  word[0] = letters[i];
  for(int j = 0; j < SIZE ;j++)
    {
      word[1] = letters[j];
      for(int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++)
      {
        word[2] = letters[k];
        for(int l = 0; l < SIZE;l++)
        {
          word[3] = letters[l];
          for(int m = 0; m< SIZE; m++)
          {
            word[4] = letters[m];
            for(int n = 0; n < SIZE; n++)
            {
              word[5] = letters[n];
              for(int o = 0; o < SIZE; o++)
              {
                word[6] = letters[o];
                  Write(word, f, 6);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

void six_Digits(char * word[],char * letters[] , FILE * f)
{
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
  word[0] = letters[i];
  for(int j = 0; j < SIZE ;j++)
    {
      word[1] = letters[j];
      for(int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++)
      {
        word[2] = letters[k];
        for(int l = 0; l < SIZE;l++)
        {
          word[3] = letters[l];
          for(int m = 0; m< SIZE; m++)
          {
            word[4] = letters[m];
            for(int n = 0; n < SIZE; n++)
            {
              word[5] = letters[n];
              Write(word, f, 5);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
void five_Digits(char * word[],char * letters[] , FILE * f)
{
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
  word[0] = letters[i];
  for(int j = 0; j < SIZE ;j++)
    {
      word[1] = letters[j];
      for(int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++)
      {
        word[2] = letters[k];
        for(int l = 0; l < SIZE;l++)
        {
          word[3] = letters[l];
          for(int m = 0; m< SIZE; m++)
          {
            word[4] = letters[m];
            Write(word, f, 4);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

void four_Digits(char * word[], char * letters[] ,FILE * f)
{
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
  word[0] = letters[i];
  for(int j = 0; j < SIZE ;j++)
    {
      word[1] = letters[j];
      for(int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++)
      {
        word[2] = letters[k];
        for(int l = 0; l < SIZE;l++)
        {
          word[3] = letters[l];
          Write(word, f, 3);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


int main()
{
  FILE *f;

  if(!(f=fopen(PATH, "a")))
  {
    perror("Errore");
    exit(-1);
  }


  char * letters[SIZE] = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z",
                          "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",
                          ".","_","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","!","@","$","§"};

  char * word13[] = {"A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A"};
  char * word12[] = {"A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A"};
  char * word11[] = {"A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A"};
  char * word10[] = {"A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A"};
  char * word9[] = {"A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A"};
  char * word8[] = {"A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A"};
  char * word7[] = {"A","A","A","A","A","A","A"};
  char * word6[] = {"A","A","A","A","A","A"};
  char * word5[] = {"A","A","A","A","A"};
  char * word4[] = {"A","A","A","A"};

 four_Digits(word4,letters, f);
 five_Digits(word5,letters, f);
 six_Digits(word6,letters, f);
 seven_Digits(word7,letters, f);
 eight_Digits(word8,letters, f);
 nine_Digits(word9,letters, f);
 ten_Digits(word10, letters,f);
 eleven_Digits(word11,letters, f);
 twelve_Digits(word12, letters,f);
 thirteen_Digits(word13,letters, f);

exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I will appreciate any help for making the alghorithm faster.

Comment: Your description is very lyrical and the code is hardly readable. Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you are asking how many 13-character words there are, it would be SIZE^13. Multiply that by 13 and you will get the size in bytes.

Answer (score 3):

This program won't finish in your lifetime -- and it'll fill up your hard disk long before that.

There are 68<sup>13</sup> = 6 × 10<sup>23</sup> possible combinations of thirteen characters chosen from a 68-character set. At 14 bytes each (13 characters + one newline), storing them all in a file would take approximately 9.3 × 10<sup>24</sup> bytes, or **9.3 trillion terabytes**. This is several orders of magnitude larger than the amount of data storage in existence on the planet.

You need to reconsider what you're trying to do here. This clearly won't work.

---

From a perspective of implementation, though, there's an easier way of approaching this than using nested loops:

```
void permute(int length, int maximum_digit)
{
    int *digits = calloc(length, sizeof(int));
    do {
        print_digits(digits, length);
    } while (increment(digits, length, maximum_digit));
    free(digits);
}
```

This function creates an array of a variable number of digits (set by `length`), and "increments" that array at each step until it has reached a maximum value (`maximum_digit`).

We can implement that incrementation by stepping through the array; for each digit, we increment it and stop if it's under its maximum value, or zero it and continue otherwise:

```
int increment(int *digits, int length, int maximum_digit)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (digits[i] + 1 == maximum_digit) {
            digits[i] = 0;
        } else {
            digits[i]++;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

An implementation of `print_digits()` is left to the reader.

Comment: I'm just curios when and where it will stop

Comment: Never. Your computer (and you) will be dust before it's even a fraction of the way done. Depending on how generous we are with our estimates, it could be anywhere between millions and billions of years…

Comment: If each word is generated,say, every nanosecond, then it will take 6x10^14 seconds. Or about 2x10^7 years. Or about 20 million years....

Comment: In almost 1 hour i got the 4-digits words and the 5-digits, the file is 10 GB.

Comment: Yes, and the 6-character permutations will take 68 times longer and 68 times more space, or about three days and 680 GB. And 7-character permutations will take 68 times longer and 68 times more space than that… and so on.

Comment: So that would be 68⁹ hours only. It would be only 3.5 trillion years. I am pretty sure that you'd actually give up some billionth of time earlier, or there would be a power outage... or if not, your computer stops working when the sun explodes or something.

Comment: i stopped the program at 15 GB and i got all the words from 4 to 6 digits(only starting with "A")

Comment: I'm doing a second run but this time i won't stop till i fill the hard  disk.

Comment: Like... You don't believe us?